# Change top margin on second page with tcpdf AcceptPageBreak()

Tags: php, fpdf, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to generate PDFs. The PDF uses a PDF-template via the fpdi-class. Some of the generated PDFs are onepaged. But sometimes I have a second page. I use $pdf->MultiCell to output my content. The page-break works fine via $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true).

Now my problem: I need a different top-margin on the second page. What I tried so far is the use of the AcceptPageBreak()-function - unfortunaly with no success.

With the following code-snipped I managed to change the margin on the second page. But it adds one empty page at the end of the PDF.

```
public function AcceptPageBreak() {

    $this->SetMargins(24, 65, 24, true);
    $this->AddPage();        
    return false;

}
```

I tried to remove the last page with $pdf->deletePage but it does not work. 
I tried to insert some conditions into the function:

```
public function AcceptPageBreak() {
    if (1 == $this->PageNo()) {
        $this->SetMargins(24, 65, 24, true);
        $this->AddPage();        
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

This works fine for PDFs with text for 2 pages. But now I get allways two paged PDFs - even if I have just a small text. It seems that the function "AcceptPageBreak()" is called every time the PDF is generated.

How can I prevent the empty page at the end of my PDF?

Answer (score 6):

Using some of your code and the original function, I found out a way where it doesn't add an unneccessary blank page at the end of the file.

```
public function AcceptPageBreak() {
         if (1 == $this->PageNo()) {
                $this->SetMargins($left_margin, $top_margin, $right_margin, true);
         }
        if ($this->num_columns > 1) {
            // multi column mode
            if ($this->current_column < ($this->num_columns - 1)) {
                // go to next column
                $this->selectColumn($this->current_column + 1);
            } elseif ($this->AutoPageBreak) {
                // add a new page
                $this->AddPage();
                // set first column
                $this->selectColumn(0);
            }
            // avoid page breaking from checkPageBreak()
            return false;
        }
        return $this->AutoPageBreak;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution to my own question.
Maybe it's interesting for someone else with the same problem.

I took the function AcceptPageBreak() like posted above (Version 1). After saving the PDF I import the PDF into a new PDF without the last page and save the new PDF.

Here the code:

```
 $pdf = new MYPDF();  

 $pdf->SetMargins(24, 54);        

 $pdf->AddPage();

 ...

 $pdf->MultiCell('0', '', $text, '', 'L');

 $pdf->lastPage();

 $lastPage = $pdf->PageNo() + 1;

 $pdf->Output($filePath, 'F');

 // remove last page

 $finalPdf = new FPDI();
 $finalPdf->setSourceFile($filePath);

 for ($i=1; $i < $lastPage; $i++) {
     $finalPdf->AddPage();
     $tplIdx = $finalPdf->importPage($i);
     $finalPdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);            
 }
 $finalPdf->Output($filePath, 'F');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

TCPDF Automatic Page Breaks cause some inconsistency in rendering of content.  Elements that may inadvertantly extend out of the boundaries of the page can cause additional pages to be generated.  It is better to only autopage break when you are adding your content using:

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $margin_bottom);
```

Then disable it when there it is not needed.

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
```